# Shimano nexus 8 internal gear shift cable holder is broken. What can I do?

Tags: shimano, shifter, internally-geared-hub, cable, nexus

I have a Cube Hyde Pro equipped with a Shimano Nexus 8. The cable holding place is broken. As you can see in the image below:[image: Shimano Nexus 8 cable holder broken]

As a temporary solution I glued it with a cyanoacrylate glue but it is not ideal and I don't know how long it will hold.

So my questions are:

- Can this plastic piece be replaced?
- Is it easy to find a replacement in Europe?
- My bike is not even 1 year old. Can this be covered by warranty?

Comment: WRT the warranty, I would expect it to cover it. You may want to have a basic understanding of the six months rule: https://philippelaw.eu/en/la-garantie-legale-dans-les-ventes-aux-consommateurs/ I reckon they should fix it for you, but they may try to fob you off. Don't give up too easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, if it is a Nexus 8, the part number should be Shimano CJ-8S20. In case I am wrong, double-check the part number. It should be printed into the steel arm that the cable housing goes in to.

It should be easy to order online in europe, I found multiple websites that allow you to do so, but I don't know if any bike shops will carry it in stock.

I am unsure of the warranty it may have, ask the store where you bought it from and contact Shimano to be find out.

[image: Shimano CJ-8S20]

Comment: with regard to bike shops, any shop that deals with shimano will be able to order the part

Comment: There is also a CJ-8S40 model, which has identical mount on hub side, but it comes with a rubber protector for the cable (some shops list it as "Nordic weather protection" :) I've tried both and couldn't see any difference though). Either one should fit and can be replaced at home if you have a wrench to remove the wheel (the mount itself is just finger tighting of the part that has "Lock" on it). But if you are replacing just the part, try to get one with the same part number because the length of the "open" wire from outer cable end to the locknut on the wire is a tad different.